# Racket / vs - for identifier delimiters

Tags: syntax, racket, convention

Most of the time in lisps (including racket) `-` is used in `identifier-delimiters`. I'm going through the racket guide and found that contracts use `/` for delimiters, for example in `define/delimiter`. In clojure `/` is for namespacing, but in racket `/` is a valid identifier character.

So the question is: What is the reason for naming it `define/contract` vs `define-contract`. Is there a convention I'm not aware of for when to use `/`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The / is short for "with".

This guide contains a list of conventions. The / convention is not in the table though.

http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/Style/style/Textual_Matters.html#%28part._names%29

Comment: It is used for exceptions. It is also used to import names from module in order to avoid name clashes. For example, if you define your own functions with the name list and still want to use the original. Then (require (prefix-in racket: racket)) will import the names from racket with a prefix. You can now use racket:list to get the original.

Answer (score 1):

Jens's answer is correct, that `/` is short for "with". This has been enshrined in the R6RS and R7RS Scheme standards, where `call/cc` is the short name for [`call-with-current-continuation`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call-with-current-continuation). (R5RS mentions it, but did not formally standardise the name the way R6RS and R7RS did.)

[image: My CALL/CC car plate]